# At what point is the thread created in RxJava

Tags: multithreading, rx-java

Say I have a bunch of transformations on an [Observable](https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava/wiki/Transforming-Observables#wiki-flatmap):

```
operation()
    .flatMap(toSomething())
    .map(toSomethingElse())
    .flatMap(toYetSomethingElse())
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .observeOn(AdroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(observer);
```

Are all of these operations synchronous except for the last call to `flatMap()`? Or are all of the operations run on the thread that I told it to subscribe on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out, with a test. The following test passes (which means the emissions on the Observable are all on the same background thread):

```
    volatile long observableThreadId;

    @Test
    public void transformedObservables_shouldRunInSameThread() {

        Observable.from(new String[]{"a", "b", "c"}) //
            .flatMap(new Func1<String, Observable<Object>>() {
                @Override public Observable<Object> call(String s) {
                    observableThreadId = Thread.currentThread().getId();
                    return Observable.from((Object) s);
                }
            }) //
            .map(new Func1<Object, String>() {
                @Override public String call(Object o) {
                    long id = Thread.currentThread().getId();
                    if (id != observableThreadId) {
                        throw new RuntimeException("Thread ID mismatch");
                    }

                    return (String) o;
                }
            }) //
            .flatMap(new Func1<String, Observable<String>>() {
                @Override public Observable<String> call(String s) {
                    long id = Thread.currentThread().getId();
                    if (id != observableThreadId) {
                        throw new RuntimeException("Thread ID mismatch");
                    }

                    return Observable.from(s);
                }
            }) //
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()) //
            .observeOn(Schedulers.currentThread()) //
            .subscribe(new Observer<String>() {
                @Override public void onCompleted() {
                    assertThat(Thread.currentThread().getId()).isNotEqualTo(observableThreadId);
                }

                @Override public void onError(Throwable throwable) {

                }

                @Override public void onNext(String s) {

                }
            });

        System.out.println("blah");
    }
```

===============================
UPDATE:

A better answer can actually be found in the ReactiveX documentation on [Scheduler](http://reactivex.io/documentation/scheduler.html):

> By default, an Observable and the chain of operators that you apply to
>   it will do its work, and will notify its observers, on the same thread
>   on which its **Subscribe** method is called. The *SubscribeOn* operator
>   changes this behavior by specifying a different Scheduler on which the
>   Observable should operate. The *ObserveOn* operator specifies a
>   different Scheduler that the Observable will use to send notifications
>   to its observers.
>
> ... the ***SubscribeOn*** operator designates which thread the Observable will
>   begin operating on, no matter at what point in the chain of operators
>   that operator is called. ***ObserveOn***, on the other hand, affects the
>   thread that the Observable will use ***below*** where that operator appears.
>   For this reason, you may call ObserveOn multiple times at various
>   points during the chain of Observable operators in order to change on
>   which threads certain of those operators operate.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more? Thanks